# Como mostrar flechas (next/prev) en el keyboard iOS para los formularios

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, reactjs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo puedo mostrar esas flechas de navegación en los formularios, intenté con varios `props` en el componente `textInput` pero ninguno me resultó.

> Si hay un método para activarlos sería genial saberlo, muchas gracias
>   por su tiempo :)

.

Comment: Tanto las flechas como el botón Done no son parte de componentes nativas de iOS, hay que agregarlos con `inputAccessoryView`. Hay [ejemplos en internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14148276/toolbar-with-previous-and-next-for-keyboard-inputaccessoryview) de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte @paulvs, esto es lo que buscaba. Un saludo.